# Duplicate values - Map

Tags: java

I have two maps Map and Map2 in which values keep on getting added. 
I need to check the if the duplicate value is being added in Map2 by comparing all the values in Map. I have written a simple function but it always give false. <--- this is my question, if duplicate exists, it should give true.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("1", "Jan");
map.put("2", "Feb");
map.put("3", "Mar");
map.put("4", "Apr");
map.put("5", "May");
map.put("6", "Jun");

List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
  System.out.println("The key is: " + mapEntry.getKey()
  + ",value is :" + mapEntry.getValue());
  String value =  (String) mapEntry.getValue();

  ids.add(value);

  //ids.addAll(mapEntry.getValue());
}

Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
map1.put("112", "Jan1");
map1.put("22", "Feb");
map1.put("31", "Ma2r");
map1.put("43", "Apr3");
map1.put("51", "May4");
map1.put("63", "Jun5");


Iterator iterator1 = map1.entrySet().iterator();
boolean exists = false;
String value1 = null;
while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) iterator1.next();
  System.out.println("The key is: " + mapEntry.getKey()
  + ",value is :" + mapEntry.getValue());
  value1 =  (String) mapEntry.getValue();




  //ids.addAll(mapEntry.getValue());
}

for(String id: ids){
  System.out.println("ids: " + id);
  exists = ids.contains(value1);
}

System.out.println("Value exist?" + exists);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are complicating your life...

[`Map` has a `.containsValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method ;)

Now, you should be more precise about your real question. Do you actually talk about a *value* or do you mean a map *entry*?

If a value, just use `.containsValue()`. If a full entry, it is as simple as:

```
// Supposes values CAN NOT BE NULL
map2.containsKey(theKey) && map2.get(theKey).equals(theValue)
```

Another solution, albeit a little more complicated but which helps if your maps are really large, is to wrap the map modification in a method where you record values in a `HashSet` in addition to storing them in the map; you can then check that the value set `.contains()` the value you want to add.

Comment: Just learned something new lol

Answer (score 3):

*Answering only to your specific question , not correcting your entire logic though.* I would like to say that since the variable `exists` is inside the loop and you are printing it after the loop , the variable value is getting overridden .

```
for(String id: ids){
    System.out.println("ids: " + id);
    exists = ids.contains(value1); // exists is assigned a new value each time here
}
System.out.println("Value exist?" + exists);
```

I guess you need to break from the loop once your `exists` is `true`.

You can use simpler API method like [containsValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to find if this specific value exists in your map, you can break out of your loop after you have found it.

This way, your variable will still be set to true after you break and it will be false if you didn't break out of your loop.

```
for(String id: ids){
  System.out.println("ids: " + id);
  exists = ids.contains(value1);
  if(exists) {
      break;
  }
}

System.out.println("Value exist?" + exists);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using:

```
int mapSize = map.values().size();
ArrayList<String> mapValues = new ArrayList<String>( map.values() );
mapValues.removeAll( map1.values() );
System.out.println( "Value exists? " + ( mapSize != mapValues.size() ) );
```

Comment: what if the op needs the data in this map after this check?

Comment: Do you mean concurrency? `mapValues` is just a throw-away list. It's not removing values from `map`.

Comment: ah okay sorry read wrong and thought you modified the map. but still much effort to avoid `contains()` ;)